# strange boot.log - multiple startpar bridge... starting and stopping repeatedly

Tags: boot

I've just encountered a very strange boot (since I have no "quiet" nor "splash" in grub options). So I've had a look in the log:

```
crysman@crysman-U36SD:~$ cat /var/log/boot.log
 * Starting Bridge file events into upstart [ OK ]
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
 * Starting SystemD login management service [ OK ]
 * Starting AppArmor profiles [ OK ] 
 * Starting bluetooth daemon [ OK ]
 * Starting startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop [ OK ]
 * Stopping startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop [ OK ]
 * Starting mDNS/DNS-SD daemon [ OK ]
 * Starting Reload cups, upon starting avahi-daemon to make sure remote queues are populated [ OK ]
 * Starting Reload cups, upon starting avahi-daemon to make sure remote queues are populated [fail]
 * Setting sensors limits [ OK ] 
 * Setting up X socket directories... [ OK ] 
 * Stopping System V initialisation compatibility [ OK ]
 * Starting network connection manager [ OK ]
 * Starting System V runlevel compatibility [ OK ]
 * Starting [ OK ]
 * Starting automatic crash report generation [ OK ]
 * Starting [ OK ]
 * Starting cups-browsed - Bonjour remote printer browsing daemon [ OK ]
 * Starting Restore Sound Card State [ OK ]
 * Starting ACPI daemon [ OK ]
 * Starting anac(h)ronistic cron [ OK ]
 * Starting [ OK ]
 * Starting [ OK ]
 * Starting save kernel messages [ OK ]
 * Starting [ OK ]
 * Starting [ OK ]
 * Stopping Restore Sound Card State [ OK ]
 * Starting CPU interrupts balancing daemon [ OK ]
 * Starting startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop [ OK ]
 * Stopping startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop [ OK ]
 * Stopping Restore Sound Card State [ OK ]
 * Starting startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop [ OK ]
 * Stopping startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop [ OK ]
 * Stopping save kernel messages [ OK ]
 * Starting regular background program processing daemon [ OK ]
 * Stopping anac(h)ronistic cron [ OK ]
```

There are repeating entries, start/stopping over and over, empty entries like " * Starting"... Why is that so? Any cause you might think of?

That "startpar bridge" and empty "Starting" entries had certainly not been there until today (I've installed some stuff).

Thanks a lot

I am running Xubuntu 13.10 (fresh install 3 days ago)
Additional debug info:

```
cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic root=UUID=751f644f-5523-465f-bbaa-ef75ed4373f1 ro i915.i915_enable_rc6=1
```

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? I have similar issue.

Comment: This bug report may be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1324627

Comment: It became resolved once I switched to Xubuntu 15.04